# Express routing in Node JS returns 404 on live server, but not test system

Tags: node.js, express

So I'm fairly new to NodeJS, and I wanted to try routing with it, however I've come across a weird issue, I'm not sure if it's my hosting provider having some weird config issue on their end.

But here's my scenario, I have a site with a fair amount of pages which are generated from a database based on locations saved in the database, so for example, if there are three cities saved in the database, I would need:

mydomain.com/BigCity

mydomain.com/OtherBigCity

mydomain.com/SmallCity

Again, these **cannot** be hard coded.

So here is my basic code for just testing the redirects:

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

// Different variations of things I have tried (including hard coding just for testing)
app.use('*', render);
app.use('/*/', render);
app.use('/*', render);
app.use('/', render);
app.use('Location2', render);
app.use('/Location1', render);

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function (r) {
    console.log('listening');
});

function render(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(path.resolve("./index.html"), "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send("An error occured");
        }

        return res.send(
            data.replace(
                '<div id="root"></div>',
                `<h1>Test</h1><b>${req.originalUrl}</b><br/><b>${req.url}</b>`
            )
        )
    })
}
```

So on my local system, it works perfectly fine, and outputs as expected, but when I deploy to my hosting, only the main url works (mydomain.com/), but no matter what I type after the domain, I get a 404 error, I'm also not even sure how to properly diagnose the issue.

To my knowledge all the items in packages.json are installed on the server (I assume I'd get an error if they weren't), only difference is my local computer has NodeJS version 16, and my host provider has v10.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of using middleware (`app.use()`), you should use [dynamic routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) with route parameters (`app.get('/:id', (rec, res) {...})`).

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const port = 3000

app.get('/:location/things-to-do', render);

function render(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(path.resolve("./index.html"), "utf-8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).send("An error occured");
      }

      return res.send(
          data.replace(
              '<div id="root"></div>',
              `<h1>Test</h1><b>${req.path}</b><br/><b>/${req.params.location}/another-path-you-can-follow</b>`
          )
      )
  })
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Be sure to sanitize any input from the user (including data from route parameters) or you open a security hole that could compromise your site or your visitors if they follow a malicious link to your page. Generally sending the value of a route parameter back to the user, as I show in the sample code above, is not a best practice.

Comment: Thank you, this didn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: Can you explain what didn't work? Can you show all your code?

Comment: That's literally the entire code, as I'm still learning routing, and trying to get it to work, the `data.replace(...)` is for testing.  I tried adding `app.get('/:location/things-to-do', render);` and I still get a 404 error.  The strangest thing is it works fine with localhost, but not when there is a domain associated.

Comment: I've now tested my code and it works as I have written it and mostly copied from your code. Are you sure you're using the correct URL? Can you retrieve a static page?

Comment: I've updated my code so that you can cut and paste exactly what's here and get it to work.

Comment: I've changed my code to only have: `app.get('/:location', (req, res) => res.send("Hello"));
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send("index"));` the index one works, but the other does not (returns 404).  I'm starting to think I might need to contact my hosting provider about this issue.

Comment: I've installed node 10.23.1 and updated to use require and everything still runs as written above.

Comment: Not sure this is obvious, but be sure to remove all the app.use(…) from your code.

Comment: I believe the issue might be something to do with the fact that it's node JS that's being redirected from an IIS server, so I need to look into a reverse proxy.

Comment: Oh, node on Windows. That's an important piece of information and probably why your provider is still on version 10. Your host is probably using iisnode. Reverse proxy is the way to go on IIS if your host lets you set it up. Reverse proxy is also used on linux when running several node servers that all need to respond on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add:

```
    <rule name="/">
      <match url="/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
    </rule>
```

to the rewrite section of web.config

Answer (score -1):

Once add your node version in your `package.json`

```
"engines": {
    "node": "14.17.5"
  },
```

Now your package.json looks like
[image]

Comment: One more thing you can do is on your live go in inspect -> network see right URL is calling for dedicated API or not

Comment: While the node version may be an issue, this doesn't fix the problem. The engines parameter is advisory only. It does not actually cause a specific version of node to be used. If you have shell access to your host server to install your own node versions, you can use a tool like nvm and .nvmrc to control which version of node will run your code.

Comment: Thanks @kevintechie unfortunately I don't have shell access, I believe I can run very basic npm scripts, but that's about it.